# How to save select option in localStorage with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, storage, selection, local

I am trying to save selected option in localStorage in HTML, so if you refresh page, the selection stays selected.

I have try this:

HTML:

```
<select id="edit">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#edit').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.innerHTML);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('todoData')){
        localStorage.getItem('todoData');
    }
});
```

But this seems not to work, any ideas, realy thanks for help...

Live Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/nwk1g6vp/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Store and set the value, not the entire HTML of the select

```
$(function() {
    $('#edit').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.value);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('todoData')){
        $('#edit').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData'));
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nwk1g6vp/2/)

Comment: Thank you, amazing snippet :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `value` property or [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function

```
$('#edit').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.value); //$(this).val()
});
if (localStorage.getItem('todoData')) {
    $('#edit').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData')).trigger('change');
}
```

[*Example*](http://jsfiddle.net/eqyovgm4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This one is also functional

```
var selected = localStorage.getItem('selected');
if (selected) { 
    $("#edit").val(selected);
}

$("#edit").change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('selected', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.