# How to save chosen Jquery selected options at same page even stay at same place after refresh the pagea

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, prototype

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css">
</head>
<body>



<form method="POST" name="" action="">
<select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" name="time" style="width:300px;" id="rememberSelected">
        <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
        <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
        <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
        <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
        <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
        <option value="30:30">03:00</option>
        <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
        <option value="05:00">04:30</option>
</select>
<button type="button">Save</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $(".chzn-select").chosen();
  });
  </script>
<script>
  $("#rememberSelected").val(localStorage.getItem("selected") || 1);

$("#rememberSelected").on("change", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("selected", $(this).val());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

how to save selected options at same place after click on the save button using chosen jquery even if I'm refresh the page selected option should stay at same place.

Comment: Possible multiple of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265744/how-to-save-select-option-in-localstorage-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the selected option into localStorage and retrieve it upon page load.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
if(!!localStorage.getItem("selected")) {
    $("#rememberSelected").val(localStorage.getItem("selected").split(",")).trigger("chosen:updated");
}

$("button").on("click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("selected", $("#rememberSelected").val());
});
```

Comment: can please  help me with that code i am very new to javascript and Jquery

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like, but I've edited my answer to include a general example.

Comment: I added your script and id to html page but after the save when i am refresh page values will rested automatically

Comment: Hi triihim please help on it I just posted my html code here please check it once

Comment: Hello Triihim I added my code at this page please check once and please let me know ASAP

Comment: Yes. The example I provided works for normal selects, but yours uses chosen multiselect. I'll take a look

Comment: @chinni I've edited my answer now to work with chosen select. Let me know if it works.

Comment: <form method="POST" name="" action="">
<select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" name="time" style="width:300px;" id="rememberSelected">
        <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
        <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
        <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
        <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
        <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
        <option value="30:30">03:00</option>
        <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
        <option value="05:00">04:30</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="getValues()">Save</button>
</form>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $(".chzn-select").chosen();
  });
  </script>
<script>
  function getValues(){
  $("#rememberSelected").val(localStorage.getItem("selected") || 1);

$("#rememberSelected").on("change", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("selected", $(this).val());
});
}
</script>

Comment: Did you try with the code in my answer after I updated it?

Comment: Yes I tried with your updated code it's working fine but there is no any click function to save  button  the values should save only when I'm click on the save button instead of your code  working like if I'm select any value that will stay at same place even page is refreshed but the thing is when i am click on the save button then stay at same place.

Comment: hi dear your code is working fine thank you very much for that, but it should (Values )stay at same place when I'm click on the save button only hope you understand

Comment: Updated the answer. Now the storing is done on button click.

Comment: Working fine absolutely..that's the sweet of you triihim. thanks a lot of your efforts also let me know  how could i follow you

Comment: Yes how to go  chat with you..and because again i had a issue code without click the save button  values  will stay at same place

Comment: hi dear i don't want it to local storage  please help on that same  issue

Answer (score 0):

You can save your state to `localStorage`

```
<script>
if (localStorage['select-state']) {
    $( "select" ).val(JSON.parse(localStorage['select-state']));
}

$( "select" ).change(function() {
    localStorage['select-state'] = JSON.stringify($(this).val());
});
</script>
```