# how to stop the select tag from resetting to default after the submission of the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select tags inside a form.
it looks like this:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" onchange="sub()">
    <select id="select-option" name="option">
        <option id="op1" value="opt1" >Opt 1</option>
        <option id="op2" value="opt2">Opt 2</option>
        <option id="op3" value="opt3">Opt 3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">sub</button>
</form>
```

the problem is when a form is submitted, everything will go back to it's default state. is there a way to stop the select tags from going back to default after the submission of the form? if there is I would like to get some ideas on how to do this using javascript or jquery?.

NOTE: I have tried the preventDefault(); but apparently this code won't let me submit my form. all i wanted is to do is to prevent the select tags to reverting back to it's default when submitting the form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save select option in localStorage with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265744/how-to-save-select-option-in-localstorage-with-jquery)

Comment: thankyou for sharing this, i will try it immediately